# Error while saving video animation in paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview

I'm using Paraview version 5.4.1 in Ubuntu 18. I have a problem while saving the animation as video.

```
vtkSMSaveAnimationProxy (0x55c8203b9380): The requested resolution '(1250, 536)' has been changed to '(1248, 536)' to match format specification.

Generic Warning: In /build/paraview-lH8wFv/paraview-5.4.1+dfsg3/VTK/IO/FFMPEG/vtkFFMPEGWriter.cxx, line 449
Problem encoding frame.

ERROR: In /build/paraview-lH8wFv/paraview-5.4.1+dfsg3/VTK/IO/FFMPEG/vtkFFMPEGWriter.cxx, line 620
vtkFFMPEGWriter (0x55c81a44ed50): Error storing image.
```

This is the error message I'm receiving.
Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Seems like you'll need to submit this as a bug to Paraview: https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues

Comment: Please don't. Try with a more recent version of ParaView, like ParaView 5.8.0.
https://www.paraview.org/download/

Comment: How many space do you have on your disk ? It can be an out of space error